# Definition of split of exact sequence

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence

In D&F, they define split as below. (383pg of third edition)

> Let $R$ be a ring and let $0 \rightarrow A \xrightarrow{\psi} B \xrightarrow{\phi} C \rightarrow 0$ be a short exact sequence of R-modules. The sequence is said to be **split** if there is an $R$-module complement to $\psi(A)$ in $B$. In this case, up to isomorphism, $B=A\oplus C$ (more precisely, $B=\psi(A)\oplus C'$ for some submodule $C'$, and $C'$ is mapped isomorphically onto $C$ by $\phi:\phi(C')\cong C$).

But then, isn't every short sequence is split? Since $\psi$ is injective and $\phi$ is surjective, $B/\psi(A) = B/Im\psi = B/ker\phi \cong Im\phi = C$, so that $B\cong \psi(A)\oplus C \cong A\oplus C$.

And also, they suggest an example(D&F, 384pg) of nonsplit exact sequence as $0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{n} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$ where $n$ sends $a$ to $na$ and $\pi$ is a natural projection. But, since $\mathbb{Z} \cong n\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, I can not find it is nonsplit.

There must be somewhere I misunderstood, but I can't find where. May I know which part is wrong?

Comment: Why would you think that $ℤ \cong nℤ \oplus ℤ/nℤ$?

Comment: Also, in more general contexts (i.e., other categories than the category of $R$-modules), a split does not imply direct sum, either.

Comment: @k.stm Thanks for the comment, now I see that part must be wrong because of torsion freeness. But I thought as that because every integer can be express as $nk+a$ uniquely(where $0\leq a < n$). Now I'm confused with why this doesn't imply $\mathbb{Z} \cong n\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ringwith1 You are thinking of this: If $M$ is an abelian group, then for subgroups $A ⊂ M$ and $B ⊂ M$ it is equivalent that $M$ splits as an *internal* direct sum $M = A \oplus B$ if and only if for every $m ∈ M$ there are unique $a ∈ A$, $b ∈ B$ such that $m = a + b$.  In your case, the latter part of the equivalence may be satisfied in some sense, but $ℤ/nℤ$ $(=B)$ just isn’t a subgroup of $ℤ$ $(=M)$ (and even not so if you regard $ℤ/nℤ$ as the subset $\{0,…,n-1\}$ of $ℤ$, because then the addition on $ℤ/nℤ$ is *not* inherited from the addition in $ℤ$).

Comment: @k.stm Now I got it clearly, thanks!